# How to change width of display:column of display tag table

Tags: java, jsp, displaytag

I have tried below snippet but its not working

```
<display:column title="Name" property="name" style="width:100%" paramId="name"  >
</display:column>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added min-width attribute in css code .

```
 .changeWidth{
min-width:300px;
}
```

and

```
<display:column title="Name" property="name" class="changeWidth" paramId="name"  >
</display:column>
```

Answer (score 1):

Width attribute will not affect display. You have o change displaytag.css

add your header this and use css for your display:

```
<link href="styles/displaytag.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```